# Elasticsearch: What's the shape/model of failures object in the delete by query response?

Tags: elasticsearch

According to the ElasticSearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-api-response-body), the delete by query response looks like this:

```
{
  "took" : 147,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 119,
  "deleted": 119,
  "batches": 1,
  "version_conflicts": 0,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}
```

How do I find out what the shape/model of the `failures` object is so that I can add failure handling logic on the client-side?

Edit: I found the `Faliure` class from the [ElasticSearch Github repository](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/feab123ba400b150f3dcd04dd27cf57474b70d5a/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/support/replication/ReplicationResponse.java#L219), which is a good starting point.